# How to avoid stacking threads while measuring clip length?

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, clip

I am making a program that play new random sounds every time one sound has finished playing. However, this means that I call the Thread t1 many times anew, and I am wondering if the program is just infinitely stacking new threads? Also, the first set of sounds I play (when I call method 2 or 3) are played right after one another, but after that there is a delay between each sound. Method 2 and 3 also has almost the same section of code as the code down below, which is not good. Any idea how to dry up the code?

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     while(clip.getMicrosecondLength() != clip.getMicrosecondPosition())
                     {

                     }
                    clip.stop();
                    clip.close();

                    method1();
                    if(i = 1) {
                        method2();
                    } else {
                        method3();
                    }
                 }
            });  
            t1.start();
```

Comment: What do you mean "stacking threads"? The threads are running in parallel.

Comment: Well, I am not very skilled in programming (my knowledge comes from self learning), and I was wondering what happens to the thread... Does it create a new thread and let the old one run in the background, or does the old one terminate, or does it use the same thread again?

Comment: Well, then, you should read the [concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). But there's something more basic you're missing: when you write `t1 = new X()`, it creates a new `X` and puts a reference to it in `t1`. The old `X` that was in `t1` is not in `t1` anymore, and there is no connection between it and the new `X`, who doesn't even know there used to be an old `X` there. Anyway, threads are designed to run in parallel, so each new one that you create and start will run alongside the old one. until its `run` terminates.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Could you see why this would affect the sound being played very late?